# How to fit smooth a curve through min/max intervals

Tags: algorithm, spline, smoothing

I have a list of numeric measurements (see the graph below). Because these measurements are imprecise, each measurement is represented as a pair `(min, max)`, where `min` (blue) is <= the actual value and `max` (red) is >= the actual value.

[image]

Now I'd like to fit a smooth curve (green) through these min/max pairs. Like bending a strip of flexible material to fit between the min/max pairs. I'm not looking for a continuous function; I'm just interested in the discrete values. That is, I'd like a single `smoothed` value for each `(min, max)` pair.

I'm sure there must be an existing algorithm for this. I just can't find it. Splines seem to be the obvious candidate, but I can't figure out how to fit a spline between min/max pairs.

Comment: This seems to be a pretty difficult problem.

Comment: With the "strip of flexible material" analogy you can apply structural civil engineering concepts. It's a beam supported in some of the min values and loaded with max values, which blend the strip. Setting the supports is easy. Solving the deformations can be done by elements connections (a matrix matter) and solving the equations or with more grained finite elements method (FEM). Too large to explain here.

Comment: @Ripi2: "Setting the supports is easy": I doubt it, you don't know on what side to support, if any. The number of possibilities is huge. The challenge is not in solving the elasticity equations, this is simulated with a spline (IMO, even a thin plate spline is overkill, natural cubic is enough). The difficulty is combinatorial.

Comment: this is a deeply interesting challenge. Have you ever found or developed a solution to this?

Comment: @AndrewSteer I'm afraid not. I gave up at some point.

Answer (score 0):

There is a brute force solution that works as follows:

- for every abscissa, choose one of three options

  1. the curve goes through the min value,
  2. the curve goes through the max value,
  3. the curve is free and doesn't use this abscissa.
- when you have performed all assignments, compute the cubic spline through the selected points.
- check that the curve does not infringe a min/max constraint at an unused abscissa.
- for the remaining valid curves, compute a merit figure such as an estimate of the total curvature.

Keep the solution that achieves the lowest total curvature.

This is only feasible for a small number of abscissas. In the given example, you should try 3^10=59049 solutions !

Maybe the complexity can be reduced by working with an increasing number of abscissas and keeping partial solutions, but this doesn't seem to be rigorous.

---

Notice that when you add points on a side of a cubic spline, the whole curve is influenced. But the influence goes diminishing as you move away, and the chances of infringing a constraint should be low.

Another line of attack could be with B-splines, which have the attractive property that new points only influence the curve in a close neighborhood.

Comment: To get rid of exponential complexity, I could calculate each smooth sample using a window of fixed size: 3 to the left, n to the right. The 3 samples on the left would already be solved (`min = max`) and supply guidance from the left. I'd have to pick a window small enough to be fast, yet large enough to give good results.

Comment: As cost function, I might simply use the number of "used" abscissas: The fewer restraints (while still within the boundaries), the smoother the resulting curve. To optimize, I could start with all combinations that use 0 abscissas to the right (there is only one), then all with 1, with 2, and so on. This way, I can stop at the first solution that doesn't infringe any constraints.

Comment: @DanielWolf: not sure this will work, as you have to blend the windows and this can cause infringements. (Not sure that the expnential complexity can be avoided at all.) The cost function is to your taste and you can very will pick the first solution that fits.

Comment: I meant overlapping windows. To calculate a given smooth value, I'd solve the entire problem for a windows 3 to the left, n to the right.

Answer (score 0):

I dont't know if this is a real solution, but I think it's at least a good start point towards the solution.

---

First detect "true" points that the solution pass through:

A "blue" point `i` is "true" if `point[i].min > point[j].max && point[i].min > point[k].max`

with `lastRedTrue < j < i` and `k > i`

A "red" point `i` is "true" if  `point[i].max < point[j].min && point[i].max < point[k].min`

with `lastBlueTrue < j < i` and `k > i`

In your example, we'll get points 3(min), 5(max) and 9(min)

Perhaps a correction is needed when two consecutive "true" blue's or red's are found.

Next, start point. The idea is

```
if firstBlue > firstRed
    startWith = blue
else
    startWith = red
```

and similar way for end point. This idea may be adjusted for a few cases.

The intermediate "true" points are discovered when a line `true[i] to true[i+1]` does not pass between `point.min` and `point.max`. I mean, both `point.min` and `point.max` lie in the same side of that line, and thus `point` is also "true".

In the example, new true points are 2(max) and 7(max)

The rest of the points must be tested not with a straight, but with the curve passing through true-points.

The final solution may need more tests due to some point losing its "true" feature because now the  line between adjacents is curved instead of straight.